# Bootstrap background body color white container + website not showing correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cloned my website [original website](http://ahepa215.org/) to make [new website](http://ahepa215.org/index2.html). On the original, the page is all white with the blue text. On the new page I tried to add

```
html {
background-color: red;

body {
color: #036;
font-size: 2rem;
background-color: #fff; }
```

This is the css for the original page

```
body {
color: #036;
font-size: 2rem;
background-color: #fff; }



 body {
 color: #036;
 font-size: 2rem;
 background-color: #fff; }
```

The original page works correctly but the new page does not show the background html red and the entire page doesn't show properly even though the html is validated. Can you help figure this out? Thanks

**EDIT I didn't ask my question correctly. I want it to appear similar to this page stnickporticons.com where the color is on the outside on the html and the middle is all white**

Comment: do you want change background color red for new page ?

Comment: Yes, but I want the main body section to be white

Comment: The background color should not be in the 'html' tag. Also there would be conflict with the background color you have in the body. It should only be in the body, and you can only choose one.

Comment: @mlegg http://imgur.com/a/AGT7J like this ? if you want this `.container: background:red;` or the opposite?  

if you want this http://imgur.com/a/Ltkjb ; 
`body {background-color:red} .container {background-color:white;}`

Comment: EDIT: that's close to what I want. I didn't ask my question correctly. I want it to appear similar to this page http://stnickporticons.com/  where the color is on the outside on the html and the middle is all white.

Comment: @mlegg please see my most recent edit. I think this may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Chis Cruze that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your "newer website" code you can see a red bar at the bottom of your page. You are applying the `background-color` to the `html` and not to the `body`

```
body {
 color: #036;
 font-size: 2rem;
 background-color: red; /*red*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your CSS for the new page, it appears that you have some syntactical errors which are causing the page to not format properly.

For example, on the new page you don't seem to have the 'html' style tag closed off.

```
html {
  background-color: red;
// Here you are missing the closing tag.

body {
  color: #036;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #fff; 
}
```

In addition, you want to set your 'background-color' in the body. Also, based on your recent comment It appears that you want two separate colors. Here is the adjusted CSS to hopefully yield the results you are looking for:

```
body {
  color: #036;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
}    

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #036;
}

.masthead img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 5rem;
  height: calc(100% - 1px);
  background-image: url('images/Ahepa215-banner.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this

```css
html {
  background-color: red;
}
body { 
  color: #036;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #fff; 
  width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto
}
```